# Как в Python запустить процеcc, потом передать ему на чтение строку, а затем выполнить команду шелла уже с новым euid?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Я студент и в одном из заданий практикума надо воспользоваться уязвимостью в бинарнике.

Декомпилировав бинарник, я выяснил, что программа после запуска считывает строку со стандартного ввода и копирует её в буфер. Буфер этот - часть структуры, в которой есть флаг, после проверки которого на равенство нулю запускается шелл уже с новым euid, с которым я могу прочитать защищённый файл.

Если дать после запуска программы ей на чтение последовательность символов нужной длины (64 байта), то флаг затрётся нулём (из-за использования strncat в программе), и программа запустит шелл с нужным eiud и я смогу ввести например cat flag_1.txt для прочтения его содержимого, чего бы я не смог сделать в нормальных условиях.

Вручную всё получается хорошо, но мне нужно написать эксплойт либо в виде башскрипта, либо скрипта на питоне.

Используя баш, я создал файл с таким содержимым:

#!/bin/sh

echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | ./task_1

при запуске этого скрипта, программа получает на вход нужную строку, флаг забивается 0, и доступ я получаю (т.к. программа ещё и пишет Access granted, так что в том, что доступ я получил, я уверен)
Однако, воспользоваться шеллом я не успеваю, так как вижу сообщение stack smashing detected или Abort (core dumped)

На питоне пытался пользоваться subprocess.call или subprocess.popen, но это тоже ничего не дало, т.к. я так понимаю, что у меня на данный момент не получается НЕ дождаться выполнения процесса, а значит и воспользоваться шеллом с новым euid я не могу, хотя Access granted тоже выводится, т.е. в нужную секцию кода я попадаю.

Почему не работает башскрипт вообще не понимаю.

Опыта у меня совсем мало, нам по сути просто дали задание без каких-либо объяснений. Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать эксплойт, или даже скорее в целом скрипт, который бы выполнял следующие действия:
1) запускал программу
2) подавал ей на чтение (не в качестве параметра командной строки, а на стандартный ввод) строку
3) позволял воспользоваться запущенным из этой программы новым шеллом для чтения сожержимого некоторого текстового файла

Comment: То, что питон тут ни при чём, я прекрасно понимаю и шелл запустить из него не пытаюсь, только саму программу запускаю.
Проблема в том, что я не могу ничего подать на вход дочернему шеллу, чтобы файл прочитать, т.к. программа завершает работу, как я понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно просто немного изменить Ваш sh-скрипт.
Вводите данные для запускаемого в `./task_1` `shell` второй командой `echo`, соединяя `stdout` обеих команд `echo` с паузой между ними:

```
#!/bin/sh

(echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; sleep 0; echo cat  flag_1.txt) | ./task_1
```

(возможно Вам потребуется `sleep 1` (у меня в Ubuntu из bash экспериментальная программа работает с 0), но боюсь тут по месту смотреть надо)

Дело тут в том, что в Вашем скрипте программа считывает все данные, выводимые `echo` и `shell`  сразу получает `EOF`.
Когда же Вы вводите данные руками, то `stdin` (`/dev/tty`), читаемый программой, остается открытым и shell успешно читает вторую вводимую строку.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, скрипт заработал. Я не знаком с работой с sh-скриптами и без Вашей помощи долго бы разбирался.

Comment: Это не только скрипты, это так unix работает.